# Add single sign on using keycloak alongside existing login

Tags: spring-boot, vuejs3, keycloak

I have an spring boot and vue application with spring security and jwt configured. Now i want to add sso using keycloak. I want to verify user using keycloak and get user information and then use it to login in my system. Like what socialite does in laravel. it redirects user to keycloak login page and then comes back with verification information.

I could not redirect to keycloak login page from spring boot.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.